# Linux grep command with complex delimiter

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have some files inside a directory:

```
140221_alzproddbadm01.log
140221_alzproddbadm02.log
140221_alzproddbadm03.log
132123_ehxsk01.log
try.sh
logs
expan
140221_alzproddbadm04.log
23891_ehxsk02.log
```

I only need to grep these:

```
140221_alzproddbadm04.log
23891_ehxsk02.log
140221_alzproddbadm01.log
140221_alzproddbadm02.log
140221_alzproddbadm03.log
132123_ehxsk01.log
```

format is not complicated (`numbers` + `_` + `bla bla bla`) but i don't know how to write right regex for my problem.

```
ls -l | grep root | cut -d " " -f9 | grep #what to write next?
```

Comment: you can pass *.log to ls and then pipe it.

Comment: there may be other log files next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$ grep -E '[0-9]*_[[:alpha:]]*.log' file
140221_alzproddbadm01.log
140221_alzproddbadm02.log
140221_alzproddbadm03.log
132123_ehxsk01.log
140221_alzproddbadm04.log
23891_ehxsk02.log
```

Or even

```
ls -l [0-9]*_[a-z]*.log | grep root | ...
```

Comment: what's that "file" word at top line?

Comment: I saved your list of files in a file `file` so that I could `grep` there.

Comment: Thank you. What about grepping them from another folder? When i show their specific folder like "ls -l /tmp/network [0-9]...." it shows all files twice. How can i solve that?

Comment: Then, you can use `ls -l /tmp/network/[0-9]*_[a-z]*.log` note there is no space in between `network` and `[0-9]`.

Comment: The shell pattern is slightly different from the regular expression; it will match any file name that starts with a numerical digit, contains an underscore, and contains at least one lower-case letter prior to `.log`.

Comment: Yes, @chepner , but I tried with `[[:alpha:]]` and could not make it work with `ls`.

Comment: It wouldn't matter; without using extended patterns, you can't repeat a particular type of match; you can only match one more arbitrary characters.

Comment: @chepner I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: `ls [[:alpha:]]*` would only match file names starting with a letter; it wouldn't be limited to file names consisting solely of letters, like the identical regular expression would. With extended patterns, you could use `ls +([[:alpha:]])`, which *would* match only a string of one or more letters.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wildcard the files appropriately ? e.g.

```
$ grep pattern *.log
```

so the shell itself will simply pass anything ending'.log' to `grep`. Note that this isn't to do with `grep` specifically but a shell [globbing function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) and thus applicable to any command.

If you have a specific list of files (`/tmp/listOfFiles.txt`) then perhaps:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
           grep pattern "$file"
    done < /tmp/listOfFiles.txt
```

See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/) for more info.

Comment: i didn't mention it in question but, there may be other log files that i don't want to grep.

Comment: That's really quite a different scenario then

Answer (score 1):

Just use `find` command:

```
find /path/to/dir -name "*\.log"
```